# Need name for font used for the Office 2013 Icons

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

I need to create a logo design similar to the icons for Office 2013:
[image: Office 2013 Icons]

Can anyone help me with font name as I am not able to find it

Comment: i don't think this is a font per se as oppose to an illustration and i would be very careful about designing a similar logo considering who created this one !

Comment: I feel its free(guessing) as I have seen many logos made in similar fashion in my research but I failed to get the font name or any similar font

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you're trying to create a 3D ribbon effect, start drawing ;)**

As others noted, this is custom. The reason you will not find a font (in addition to Microsoft's IP lawyers) is the complex shading. The commonly accepted font formats do not support illustrative gradients and borders.

**Besides, the effect in the MS example could be greatly improved upon.** The `P` in particular has some folding issues. And although the `O` doesn't look that bad, it doesn't fit the paradigm set up by the other characters.

Answer (score 6):

I highly doubt this is a font. Each letter is a custom illustration.

Answer (score 6):

[Nasalization Heavy](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/nasalization/heavy/) look close, like Scott said I'm also doubt but i think they used this font for customization.

[image]

Comment: thanx pretty close to the one I asked for